# 3 domains pointing to 3 sites which have different content and some same content

Tags: seo

My client currently has a .uk domain which points to SITE A. He had come up with an idea to purchase a .com and .au domain which will point to SITE B and SITE C. SITE A, SITE B and SITE C will have different content for university page. University page contains lots of sub pages (different kinds of universities) which will not be the same with SITE A, SITE B and SITE C. However all the 3 sites will have exactly the same content and design of home page, about us page, contact us page. Will this still be bad for SEO? If yes, I have an idea to put a canonical link for home page, about us page and contact us page to point to SITE A. Any thoughts about this?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Best Regards,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is international variations you probably want to use the rel hreflang tag. That way you can indicate they are duplicates targeting different regions.

Comment: This is the correct advise.

More info here, especially right at the bottom:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192#3

Answer (score 1):

If only those three pages have duplicate content they won't run into any issues. It takes a lot of duplicate content for it to become a problem with SEO. But using a canonical URL certainly couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

you could also exclude indexing duplicated pages on site B & C via robots.txt

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to have unique design on each page, since you cannot use canonical element on more then one domain.

Anyway, if the content is unique and useful, I don't think you should have any problems because your 'about' or 'contact' page is the same.

On the other hand, if you are concerned about this, you don't have to use identical 'about' and 'contact' page. Just add a little imagination and change it a little bit and that will do.  At least, I would do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you will define canonical tag in home page, about us page and contact us page in Site B and Site C that is pointing to site A, then you will not able to get SEO benefits from Site B and Site C.

You have to make some changes in designing and changing the content to get better SEO result from all these three sites.